# QNetworkAccessManager cause the warning: QWaitCondition: destroyed while thread is still running

Tags: c++, qt

```
void QGCCore::getLatestGCSVersion()
{
    QString url = "http://xxxxx";
    QNetworkRequest newRequest(url);
    newRequest.setUrl(url);

    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(downloadFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    networkManager->get(newRequest);
}

void QGCCore::downloadFinished(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

The above code, with empty constructor and destructor.
If I start the software and close it, it gives warning:

```
QWaitCondition: destroyed while thread is still running.
```

However, if I wait a while to close this, then it is Ok...
What's going wrong here?

Comment: Try to check `QNetworkReply::isFinished()` at finished slot

Comment: If not, then what to do?

Comment: You mean abort it in the slot?

Comment: BTW, in the downloadFinished slot, I found the reply->isFinished() returns true.